Stripe API - How to display apple pay only on PaymentElement
In my application I have flow where user needs to add payment method and then it's charged later in future.
So basically what I'm doing is that frontend is pinging aplication backend to create stripe setup_intent:
 def setup_intent
    if current_account.stripe_id.blank?
      render json: { data: nil, status: 'No customer ID found' }, status: :not_found
      return
    end

    options = {
      customer: current_account.stripe_id,
    }

    if params[:payment_method_type].present?
      options[:payment_method_types] = [params[:payment_method_type]]
    else
      options[:automatic_payment_methods] =  { enabled: true }
    end

    setup_intent = Stripe::SetupIntent.create(options)

    data = {
      client_secret: setup_intent.client_secret,
      id: setup_intent.id,
    }

    render json: { data: data, status: "success" }, status: :ok
  rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
    render json: { data: nil, status: "Error: #{e.message}" }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end

With backend response frontend get client_secret which is then used to create PaymentElement available in stripe.js:
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v2/payment_methods/setup_intent', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${bearerToken}`
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            const elements = stripe.elements({
                clientSecret: response.data.client_secret,
                loader: 'auto',
            });

            // https://docs.stripe.com/js/elements_object/create_payment_element
            const paymentElement = elements.create("payment", {
                layout: "auto",
            });

            paymentElement.mount('#payment');

            document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', async function(event) {
                // https://docs.stripe.com/js/setup_intents/confirm_card_setup
                const response = await stripe?.confirmSetup({
                    elements,
                    redirect: 'if_required',
                    confirmParams: {
                        return_url: 'http://localhost:3000',
                    },
                });

                if (!!response?.error) {
                    alert(response.error.message);
                    return;
                }
            })
        });

Thing is that on one screen of my application I need PaymentElement which will save only card as payment options and on another one only paypal and on one only apple pay. Everyting is working fine for card and paypal but I'm stuck with apple pay.
For example when I want to display only card in PaymentElement I'm using following url:
http://localhost:3000/api/v2/payment_methods/setup_intent?payment_method_type=card

and for paypal:
http://localhost:3000/api/v2/payment_methods/setup_intent?payment_method_type=paypal

But when I want to display apple pay:
http://localhost:3000/api/v2/payment_methods/setup_intent?payment_method_type=apple_pay

I got error:
{
    "data": null,
    "status": "Error: The payment method type \"apple_pay\" is invalid. See https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents/create#create_setup_intent-payment_method_types for the full list of supported payment method types. Please also ensure the provided types are activated in your dashboard (https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/payments/settings) and your account is enabled for any features that you are trying to use."
}

If I don't send payment_method_type query string to route, backend will create setup_intent with automatic_payment_methods: {enabled: true} and initiating PaymentElement with that client_secret apple pay is showing fine.


Did you confirm this part "Please also ensure the provided types are activated in your dashboard (https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/payments/settings) and your account is enabled for any features that you are trying to use." Seems like you can check it through the API docs. Interestingly though I don't see it listed as a "payment_type" Here

@engineersmnky I'm sure I enabled apple pay in payments settings. Otherwise payment element wouldn't render apple pay in safary as possible option when saving payment method

The Apple Pay payment method is a digital wallet in the true sense that it is just a convenience wrapper around the Card payment method (with a few bells and whistles).  This is why neither apple_pay nor google_pay are valid payment method types.
Because of this, you need to have the card payment method enabled for your Setup Intent in order to show Apple Pay.  For the Payment Element this will still render the card option.
To render just the Apple Pay UI, I recommend you use the Express Checkout Element.  It defaults to showing all digital wallet and wallet-like payment method types (ApplePay, GPay, PayPal, etc.) but you can

Turn off any you do not want
Specify which wallets you want to display when you create the element in Stripe.js


thanks for explanation. I read the links you send and if I understood correctly Express Checkout Element is used for one click payment. What I need here is to save apple or google as customer payment method.

You can use it to save payment methods but that's a good call out.  They should add that scenario to the docs.
To save PMs, you would create Stripe elements using mode: 'setup' and, in the confirmation step you would create a SetupIntent instead of a PaymentIntent to get the client_secret.  Lastly, you would call the confirmSetup() function instead of confirmPayment()
